# Cannot write concurrently to file from more than 5 threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am starting 20 threads in a for loop to write into a file like this:

```
for (FileSearcher & searcher : searchers)
{
    searcher.start([&sf](std::string & fileName, int & id)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //sf << "T " << id << " " << fileName << i << "\n";
            std::string msg("T ");
            msg += std::to_string(id);
            msg += " ";
            msg += fileName;
            msg += std::to_string(i);;
            msg += "\n";
            sf.writeLine(msg);
        }
    });
```

The searcher.start() function starts the thread that will execute the lambda passed as a parameter.
The sf object owns the actual file that is written by the threads and a mutex which is locked by a std::lock_guard in the sf.writeLine().

The problem is that only 5 threads are writing simultaneously to the file and after one of them finishes the job, the next one starts writing simultaneously with the other 4 threads that are not finished yet. And so on until all the 20 threads finished.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't all 20 threads write simultaneously to the file and not 5 at a time?

Here is the complete code:

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FileSearcher.h"
#include "SafeFileStream.h"

int main()
{
SafeFileStream sf("D:\\x.txt");

//sf.writeLine("hellow");
FileSearcher searchers[20];

for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
{
    searchers[j].setFileName("Some file name.txt");
    searchers[j].setId(j);
}

for (FileSearcher & searcher : searchers)
{
    searcher.start([&sf](std::string & fileName, int & id)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //sf << "T " << id << " " << fileName << i << "\n";
            std::string msg("T ");
            msg += std::to_string(id);
            msg += " ";
            msg += fileName;
            msg += std::to_string(i);;
            msg += "\n";
            sf.writeLine(msg);
        }
    });
}


for (FileSearcher & searcher : searchers)
{
    searcher.join();
}

return 0;
}
```

FileSearcher.h

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>

class FileSearcher {

private:
   std::unique_ptr<std::thread> searcher;
   std::string fileName;
   std::ifstream inputFile;
   int id;

public:
   FileSearcher();
   FileSearcher(const int &, const std::string &);
   ~FileSearcher();

   void start(std::function<void(std::string &, int &)>);
   void join();
   void setFileName(const std::string &);
   void setId(const int &);
};
```

FileSearcher.cpp

```
#include "FileSearcher.h"

FileSearcher::FileSearcher() {}

FileSearcher::FileSearcher(const int & id, const std::string & fileName)
{
    this->fileName = fileName;
    this->id = id;
}

FileSearcher::~FileSearcher()
{
    if (this->searcher->joinable())
    {
        this->searcher->join();
    }
}

void FileSearcher::setFileName(const std::string & fileName)
{
    this->fileName = fileName;
}

void FileSearcher::setId(const int & id)
{
    this->id = id;
}

void FileSearcher::start(std::function<void(std::string &, int & id)>   searchingMethod)
{
    this->inputFile.open(this->fileName);
    this->searcher = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new    std::thread(searchingMethod, std::ref(this->fileName), std::ref(this->id)));
}

void FileSearcher::join() 
{
   if (this->searcher->joinable())
   {
       this->searcher->join();
   }
}
```

SafeFileStream.h

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class SafeFileStream
{
private:
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    std::string fileName;
    std::mutex mu;
    std::unique_ptr<std::lock_guard<std::mutex>> lockGuard;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueLocker;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> safeQueueHandler;

public:
    SafeFileStream(std::string);
    SafeFileStream(SafeFileStream&&);
    ~SafeFileStream();
    template <typename T> void writeLine(T);
    template <typename T> void write(T msg);
};

SafeFileStream::SafeFileStream(std::string fileName) : fileName(fileName)
{
    this->outputFile.open(fileName);
}

SafeFileStream::SafeFileStream(SafeFileStream&& sfFileStream)
{
    this->fileName = sfFileStream.fileName;
}

SafeFileStream::~SafeFileStream()
{
    this->outputFile.close();
}

template <typename T> void SafeFileStream::writeLine(T msg)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(this->mu);
    this->outputFile << msg << "\n";
}

template <typename T> void SafeFileStream::write(T msg)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(this->mu);
    this->outputFile << msg;
}
```

Comment: You have only 5 cores?

Comment: Define "only 5 threads are writing simultaneously to the file". The lock appears to allow only one thread to write to the file, at any given time.

Comment: @Siyuan Ren I have 4 cores

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik "only 5 threads are writing simultaneously to the file" - I mean that 5 threads are writing concurrently to the file. The other 15 are passive. If one of the active threads finishes writing, then one of the passive thread activates and starts writing concurrently with the other 4 active threads.

Comment: As far as I know, the standard provides no guarantee about "fairness" in thread scheduling, or that threads waiting on a mutex will acquire ownership of it in any particular order.

Comment: What part of "the lock appears to allow only one thread to write to the file" you couldn't understand? That's what the mutex is for. It is impossible to have 5, 4, 3 or 2 threads writing to the file at the same time, with this code. The mutex guarantees that it's always one thread. Whatever's telling you five threads are writing to a file, you're not reading this data correctly.

Comment: He is writing 100 lines per thread, so I'm sure he can see that 5 threads are trying to print their 100 lines simultaneously. The lock is used for each line, not the whole task. What is the output of `std::thread::hardware_concurrency();`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that 2 ore more threads can't write at the EXACT same moment in time, because of the lock. As Elijan9 mentioned the lock is the writeLine() function, this function is called by each thread 99 times. All that I'm  trying to say is that in the output file thread no.6 doesn't start writing to the file until the thread no.1 finishes the for loop, and thread no.7 doesn't start writing until thread no.2  finishes the for loop.... And this is not normal because I haven't locked the for loop, I've locked the writeLine() function. `std::this_thread::yield()` resolved the problem.

Comment: @Elijan9 `std::thread::hardware_concurrency();` did not work. Thank's for your hint anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot determine the timing of context switching.
it's up to Operating System.
but you can "ask" the context switching to the Operating system.

call std::this_thread::yield(); after sf.writeLine(msg);

```
for (FileSearcher & searcher : searchers)
{
    searcher.start([&sf](std::string & fileName, int & id)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //sf << "T " << id << " " << fileName << i << "\n";
            std::string msg("T ");
            msg += std::to_string(id);
            msg += " ";
            msg += fileName;
            msg += std::to_string(i);;
            msg += "\n";
            sf.writeLine(msg);
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    });
```